# How to add 30 minutes to time as hours and minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Have a `time` variable which is f.ex `5:21` . I want to add 30 minutes to it, then whatever result is, I want to add 30 minutes to it. How can I do this in javascript?
Ie. I want the interval of 30 min to the time I have.

```
var time = valgraph.datetime; // it's a dynamic time
var times = time.replace('Z', '');
var res = times.substr(11, 5); // time AS 5:20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way to add minutes to your time string.

```
function addMinutesToTime(time, minsAdd) {
  function z(n){ 
     return (n<10? '0':'') + n;
    };
  var bits = time.split(':');
  var mins = bits[0]*60 + +bits[1] + +minsAdd;
  return z(mins%(24*60)/60 | 0) + ':' + z(mins%60);  
} 

result=addMinutesToTime('5:31',30);
alert(result);
```

SEE [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2gwg2k65/)

Comment: want to check my time comes under what interval for example if it is 10.45 then it should go under 10:30-11:00 interval , if it is 12:50 then it should go under 12:30 - 1:00 interval ? any idea bout this

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
 // dateTime is the variable having your own date
     var d = new Date(dateTime);
     d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 30);
```

Comment: i dont want current date i want to pass my own time

Comment: passed a parameter called dateTime which contains actual date and time as your wish..

Comment: it returns 1425707514000 ?